is it okay to mock a database when writing unit test?
I read an article about unit testing by Vladimir Khorikov, written in 2020. Here is The Article
https://vkhorikov.medium.com/dont-mock-your-database-it-s-an-implementation-detail-8f1b527c78be
It said that you shouldn't mock an (internal) application database because it's a managed dependency. Here is the relevant part:

Managed dependencies — out-of-process dependencies you have full control over. These dependencies are only accessible through your application; interactions with them aren’t visible to the external world. A typical example is the application database. External systems don’t access your database directly; they do that through the API your application provides.

And here is the part where it said that managed dependencies should use real instances:

Only unmanaged dependencies should be replaced with mocks. Use real instances of managed dependencies in tests.

However, in Khorikov's book "Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns", also from 2020 , the author said that unit test should isolate from each other and should not reach out to a shared state.
Here's the part of the book where the author said it:

Isolating tests from each other means it’s fine to exercise several classes at once as long as they all reside in the memory and don’t reach out to a shared state

So, which one is the right one? How can you use real instances of the managed dependencies/database when the criteria of a unit test should be isolated from each other?
Is there any mistake in my understanding?

... Moreover, in that Medium article, the author writes at the end "Of course, using real instances of managed dependencies in tests poses an obvious issue: how do you test them such that your tests remain fast and reliable? You’ll see this subject covered in depth in my book: Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns" - so the answer to your question seems to be somewhere in the book, I guess.

Make controversial statement, tell reader to pay money to hear the justification. Not a fan.

It might be okay to mock or not mock a dependency depending on the situation.  There are advantages to getting the tests up and running with less development time, but there are also advantages to getting the tests to run faster and with less setup and fewer resources.  If mocking a dependency is extraordinarily difficult, however, it may be a sign that your concerns aren't separated well enough.  One thing that's not helpful, in my experience, is bitter controversy over what the One True Test Methodology is.

@SebastianRedl: to be fair, I don't think it is "unethical" for a book author to write a blog entry about his book where he shares some of his ideas for free. Sure, this is also advertisement, but definitely not hidden advertisement. I think it is quite normal that the blog will be more terse than the book, and it is not surprising that because of the terseness some people might find "controversial" statements in that.

@DocBrown It's definitely not hidden advertising, and I don't object to advertising in an article. I think, however, that it should take the form of "here's an idea, if you want it in more detail and more ideas from me, buy the book". This article feels more like "here's half an idea, if you want the rest buy the book", and I don't like that.

After finally getting access to a copy of the book, I found the citation

Isolating tests from each other means it’s fine to exercise several classes at once as long as they all reside in the memory and don’t reach out to a shared state

in chapter 2 "What's a unit test?" (specifically in 2.1.2 "The isolation issue: The classical take").
The explanation about "not mocking an application database because it's a managed dependency", however, is in chapter 10, which belongs to part 3, "Integration testing".
This clear distinction has been lost in that Medium article, and it should answer your question: when writing "classical" unit tests, it is fine to mock your database, but when writing integration tests, try to treat internal databases as implementation details.
Hence, my recommendation: don't take any such blog article too literally without going through the details of their primary sources (even when both come from the same author).

So you're focussing on the relevance of a single chapter heading, and ignoring the fact his entire book is titled "Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns". That's besides how he's conflated the concepts of unit tests and integration tests in his article too. It's very charitable indeed to suggest we should read more of this author rather than less!

@Steve integration testing is a form of unit testing, technically. It uses the same technical tools, but tests application components in combination rather than separately.

@jwenting, it's certainly a form of testing, but "unit testing" surely relates to the testing of "units", not the testing of any kind of assemblage or system of them. At least that's my understanding.

@Steve There is no universal agreed definition of where unit tests ends and integration tests begin. I don't know what definition Khorikov uses, but it is perfectly reasonable to argue that a test which involves a database is a unit test if that database can be considered an implementation detail inside the unit under test and the test runs in isolation from other tests. In any case, the terminology is not the important issue, the question is if mocking the database in automated tests results in more or less robust code.

@Steve: I am not focussing on the relevance of a "single chapter heading". I recommend you have a look into the book, too, before judging. And yes, though the book is titled "Unit Testing ...", it also contains a clearly separated section about integration testing, That does not make the book worse,

@jwenting: depends on whether you are talking about unit/module integration tests or about system integration tests. This mixup has confused many people.

@jwenting Integration testing is not a form of unit testing. Integration testing and unit testing are both a form of testing. It's true that on a structural level, there's not a lot of technical difference between the two; but that doesn't inherently mean that one is a subset of the other. They're different concepts whose technical implementation is not as different as their overall goal/purpose/value is.

@JacquesB "In any case, the terminology is not the important issue" Au contraire. Terminology is the issue here. Pretty much everyone who has posted on this page agrees that the test methodology is valid in and of itself (none have contradicted it), the main pushback is on the name for it, i.e. that it's not a unit test if it includes an IO component. I'm not mentioning this because it's my opinion, but because it's the entire point of this posted answer, i.e. that the solution to the posted question is to realize that the given advice applies to integration tests, not unit tests.

@Flater it tends to use the same testing libraries and tools, hence I consider it (from a technical perspective as a software engineer) to be related.

@jwenting A software engineer should be well aware that things being related is not equivalent to therefore one being a derivation of the other - they can just as easily have a common ancestor (without being each other's ancestor) or merely resemble one another.

@Flater I'm saying the unit test/integration test distinction is unimportant because the question is not about this distinction, the question is about isolation and mocking.

The source material you're reading is plain wrong. Unit tests mock external dependencies. Who designed this dependency is irrelevant. If it's external to the unit under test, it shouldn't be included as a real component in those unit tests.
The most optimistic interpretation of this guide might be that they got confused between unit and integration tests. But that is such a straightforward easy-to-spot mistake to make, which is really egregious in a guide that otherwise attempts to rigorously defined everything to then give you specific rules about every specific thing.
I've never seen the value in distinguishing between the different kinds of fake dependency, but this article goes to great lengths to define it all. I disagree with that take, not so much the exercise of naming things in and of itself (to each their own), but the undertone that there are very different treatments based for all these fake dependency variants.
In my opinion, it's an act of creating an arbitrary distinction only to then be able to sell your guide that helps you navigate said arbitrarily complex maze of rules. The article's content feels bloated with the intention of appearing to convey more information than is actually relevant in practice.
The article ending itself on a cliffhanger that suggests you should read (and therefore buy) their book seems to further support this interpretation of the article's content.
For this article to take such a declarative stance with such granularity, and then plainly fail on the advice on what should be faked in a unit test, makes it a really bad article. Them doubling down on the "because you control/manage it" argument further compounds how misguided this article is.
I'm not saying everything in this article is wrong, but I wouldn't trust any of it based on this article alone.

I did not read Khorikov's book, but I am under impression your judgement may be a little bit premature. In that Medium article, when he wrote about "not mocking an application database". he did not write "because you designed it", he wrote "because it is under your own control" - I think that's an important difference, because when we have things under our own control, we are able to improve their testability. Unfortunately, to understand the POV of the author in full, I think we need to read his book.

@DocBrown You're correctly pointing at something that I phrased inaccurately but there's no practical difference in terms of how correct I consider the article to be. Unit tests shouldn't even be testing the entire codebase (i.e. dependency graph from top to bottom), and all of those classes are definitely under our own control and designed by us. I also think withholding judgment on an article just because the article promises to reveal more in a (paid) book is a facile argument to (a) increase sales and (b) evade any responsibility for what is plainly bad advice to begin with.

@DocBrown: To put it differently, if it couldn't be correctly explained in the scope of an article alone, then the article should not have been written. On the assumption that the author actually knows better than my interpretation of their words, this reads like a cliffhanger/clickbait ad for a book, not a meaningful guide.

That the article has clearly the purpose of advertising the author's book. But I think your critics ("source material you're reading is plain wrong") may be a little bit too harsh.

@DocBrown: I appreciate that take but I do genuinely believe the specific takeaway OP is focusing on is (a) correctly interpreting what the article states and (b) dead wrong. In the last paragraph I do try to point out that not necessarily everything in the article is incorrect, to avoid any inference that everything in the article is dead wrong.

When I got you right, you are a proponent of one of the classical unit testing "school's of thought" mentioned in that article. Khorikov tries to give us a different point-of-view on unit testing, and he is not making a secret of it. Just saying "his point of view is wrong because it is not the classical POV" does not convince me. Not saying that his POV is really "the correct" or "the better" one.

@DocBrown I don't disagree on it being a valuable test in and of itself, I disagree that it's a unit test. I hope we can agree on the definition that a unit tests should test the unit under test (and nothing else), hence distinguishing it from an integration test (more than one unit under test). The remaining assertion then is whether the database counts as part of the unit. To which I say no, a database is about as clear as you can get in terms of what is an external dependency. The very nature of a persistence device is that it is external so that its state can survive runtime restarts.

@DocBrown It sounds to me that the given advice of using a real database is trying to sell the idea of an integration test, or at least a partial integration test (i.e. not the whole stack top to bottom, but a subset of it). I have nothing against that test in and of itself but when it is sold as being a unit test, it conflicts with every possible reasonable interpretation of what constitutes a unit in unit testing., Even for the widest reasonable interpretations of a unit, an external database is a very important (IO) bridge too far.

@Flater: I expect part of the problem to be that the integration test tools I have used have been using unit testing frameworks as a base; which is to say that integration tests can be considered a subset of unit tests - it's just that the "Unit" being tested is a "Unit of Integration.".

@AlexanderThe1st: I repeat my prior mention of that being a facile argument to evade any responsibility. "A unit can be anything as long as you call it a unit" is not a meaningful justification. I'm aware you're calling out that someone else made this facile argument (i.e. the designer of the tools you used), but this also adds the twist that on a technical level (which is what a tool's implementation cares about), there's nothing different between an integration test or a unit test (especially a unit test with a unit that consists of multiple classes). The difference is conceptual.

@Flater "Unit tests mock external dependencies." - this is the crux of the discussion. Khorikov distinguish between the "classic school" which only mocks things external to the application and the "London school" which mocks every dependency of the unit under test. Clearly Khorikov favors to the classical school. His point about database is if they are wholly managed by the application, they should not be considered external and not mocked. This is a reasonable argument if you belong to the classical school. But if you belong to the "London school" databases should be mocked in any case.

@JacquesB: If everything the application manages is real in this test, then either you've got no discrete components in your codebase to begin with (at which point this whole discussion is moot) or you do have discrete components but are not testing them individually, thus making this an integration test of the application. I don't disagree about the value of the test, I disagree calling it a unit test. If you test the entire application (self-managed stack), calling that a "unit" for the purpose of being able to call its test a unit test is pointless semantical wordplay.

@Flater a unit is a part of the whole application, but a unit can itself be composed of encapsulated sub-components. So lets say you have component A with no dependencies and component B which depends on A but encapsulate this dependency. Then you would have unit tests of both A and B, but the tests of B should not "know" that B uses A, since unit tests should only not be coupled to implementation details of the unit it is testing.

@JacquesB: I'm not disagreeing with your point that a unit can consist of more than one thing (e.g. class) but the whole stack is not a meaningful definition of a unit, let alone a database hosted on an external machine behind an IO interaction. The latter most definitely is not part of the unit, and that is what the posted question is about.

@Flater: If by "the whole stack" you mean the entire application including the UI then I agree with you. But this is not what Khorikov is arguing. He is arguing that a database which is entirely encapsulated and managed by a unit should be tested as part of that unit, because it can be considered an implementation detail.

I think the inconsistency you see is just a misunderstanding. When he says you shouldn't mock the database he doesn't mean that all tests should run against a real persistent database. If that was the case, a test might change data in such a way it would affect the following tests. This is a no-go.
More likely means something like using the real database engine, but creating fresh data per test and reset the data after each test. For example you could have an SQL script which drops all tables and then recreated them in a known state, before each test. This is a common pattern for automated tests.
When he talks about shared state in the third quote, it is about isolating tests against each other, i.e. a test should not affect shared state in such a way that it might affect the outcome of other tests.
Regarding the question "is it okay to mock a database when writing unit test?" - yes it is OK in the sense that you wont get arrested for it. But as a general rule, the less you mock the better. Using mocks easily lead you down the road where your tests are just testing the mocks rather then the actual code.

That's a lot of interpolation of things Khorikov forgot to mention! Also, with database applications, controlling how they share data between clients and across sessions, and whether they do it correctly, is the main design challenge. It's arguably of very limited benefit to involve the "real" database rather than a mock, and all the complexity of that involvement and the scripting of the setup and reset, if you're not testing the sharing or evolutionary aspects.

@Steve This depends on the kind of application. For a data-driven applications a significant part of complexity might be in queries and database operations.

Agreed, but unless you're testing something in the database layer specifically (i.e. the part under test is that part of the database layer which would otherwise be a mock when testing non-database-layer parts), or testing a client-side part that is somehow tightly coupled to the database and can't easily be isolated from the database layer using a mock, then there's a considerable overhead to setting-up and resetting a real database engine when such setting-and-resetting would be only incidental to the purpose of performing a unit test of a non-database part.

@Steve It really depends on the application.  The last system I worked on had a relatively simple structure and it was quicker and easier to create and populate a bit of test data than to keep mocks up to date.

Important lesson: your confusion is not your fault.  The literature sucks.

So part of the problem you are running into is that there are many definitions of "unit test", which aren't all consistent with each other.  Furthermore, there are multiple reasons that someone might want a "unit test", and the different reasons that you might want them introduce different constraints on the design of the test.

Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we get by just doing it.

The constraints of "unit tests" follow from the "what we want".

For example, if your "unit tests" are tests written by developers for developers (for example, when practicing Test Driven Development), then one of the important constraints is that the suite of tests should be eyeblink fast (because they are going to be run so often, and we need to ensure that running the tests doesn't introduce a delay long enough to trigger a context shift).
So when Michael Feathers wrote in 2005:

A test is not a unit test if:

It talks to the database....


Feathers is working specifically in a context where the developer's attention is on improving the internal quality of the design; the extra overhead of talking to a live database, even a managed one, puts the flow in jeopardy.

On the other hand, if you are creating unit tests for testing (for example, to catch errors before your changes are automatically deployed to production), then different constraints are in play -- we don't have to worry about our test automation getting distracted by testing delays, and this eases some of the constraints that impact the design of our "unit tests".

As for why Khorikov's answers seem to be inconsistent... well, the generous answers are that he learned something during the interval between writing those things, or there may have been some subtle difference in context that changes his recommendations.
Less generously: perhaps he's just wrong.  It happens.

Side comment:  When a suite of automated tests is "eyeblink fast" or indeed any value of "swift" relative to build time for the project then the cost of running the entire suite is practically zero -- and therefore the suite should be run as often as the dev team can run it, preferably on every build.  Marginal cost of zero => quantity produced near infinite.

If you mock the DB in your test, make that clear.
Don’t expect me to know that because you called it a unit test. I’ve seen things called a unit test for no better reason then that they were run with jUnit.
If you mock something out you aren’t testing it. If you don’t test it don’t act surprised if what it does surprises you.
Maybe it’s not yours. Maybe someone else tested it and you trust them. Fine. Just make that clear.
Maybe you worked real hard to make sure the code under test was deterministic so the test would be reliable. Fine. Make that clear.
Just because a test exists doesn’t mean it has to test anything besides what it cares about. Just make clear what it cares about. That way we know what has and hasn’t been tested.
That’s what’s important. Not this unit vs integration stuff. That is literally arguing semantics.


[...] Here is the relevant part:

[...] A typical example is the application database. External systems don’t access your database directly; they do that through the API your application provides.


It's actually difficult to fully make sense of what the book author Khorikov is saying, or even what context he is working in and where his remarks might make contextual sense.
An "application database" is in general accessed by multiple clients or multiple users at once, concurrently.
Whilst database engines can be pressed into all kinds of service, a single-user, single-thread database application is the exception rather than the rule. And such usage is the simplest possible usage of a database engine which involves the least amount of design complexity and requires the least amount of professional advice.
And database engines already inherently provide an API, and independent management tools, and direct backup and restore, and so on.
Whilst it's true (and common) that you can provide a further, application-specific API in front of the general API which a database engine provides, and whilst it may be true that nothing but instances of your own application would be accessing the database so that no "external systems" access it directly (save for supervisor activity occuring directly against the database via its own API and management tools), it's a very big stretch to characterise any part of the client application plus the database as together being a "unit" in the context of unit testing.
There's actually a risk here that Khorikov is talking so much nonsense and using terms in such strange ways that we're completely disoriented by it in Goebbelsian style, and can't even readily point out how it is false.
A more charitable interpretation might be that there is some kind of context missing - either not reproduced in the question because Khorikov has been selectively quoted, or because Khorikov has tackled something too complicated for his own capability as an author, so that legitimate thinking comes across in a confused way to the reader.
But any road, there seems enough to say that Khorikov can't be taken at face value, and that what he means is simply not clear.
The sky won't fall in just because you are "unit testing" things that are not in fact units in the conventional sense. But you might end up with a confused idea of what other people mean by "units", and you might end up struggling to apply other advice about "unit tests" which assume a conventional meaning of the word.

Database state can be isolated

Isolating tests from each other means it’s fine to exercise several classes at once as long as they all reside in the memory and don’t reach out to a shared state

While the database as a whole is shared state, one can isolate the unit tests from each other. To use an analogy, the filesystem is shared state, but if you have a unit test which needs to read and write files the unit tests can create its own temp directories and temp files to isolate themselves from each other.
Similarly, unit tests which must read and write to a database can isolate themselves using transactions. One could make a new database and load a fresh schema for every unit test, but this rapidly gets expensive. For efficiency, the test suite begins by creating and initializing a schema. Unit tests can share the schema because it (usually) will not be changed; you can ensure this by removing the test's permission to make schema changes. Unit tests then isolate their database changes with transactions and other means.
Use the Repository Pattern to isolate database queries
If I'm using an ORM and wish to test a method on a model representing a table, it makes little sense to mock the database. An ORM model is intimately tied to the database. The whole point is whether or not the queries work. Eventually, one has to test the real database calls.
But what if you have a query in a method that's not intimately tied to the database? For example, one that displays the top 10 users. This might feature a database call, but it isn't really about the call. This is a good candidate for extracting that query into its own method. You could make it part of a model, but this runs the risk of fat models.
Better would be to use the repository pattern to add a layer between the data and the application. This isolates all your queries in one place, and it decouples the design from the database schema. The application layer asks repository classes to speak to the database. Unit testing the application mocks the repository classes.
Only unit tests for the repository classes use a real database; they must because the repository classes are intimately tied to the database and schema.
The result is you never have to mock the database itself, only the repository classes.

Terminology, and personal preferences/project guidelines aside, it depends.
Let's take two scenarios:
Function A
This function is expected to do some complex calculations and then do a simple CRUD to a table.  The "brains" are in the client code and the database only serves to save state.
A mock, if commonly used in the project, is reasonable enough.
Function B
This function either calls a stored procedure or it launches one or several complex queries in order to compute some results.  The "brains" are more in the queries themselves.
If your app is database-centric, it doesn't make as much sense to use a mock because most of the actual real life complexity of the application resides in the database.
Other factors

Are the database or queries read-only?  That would lessen the need for Mocks

How "heavy" is your database?  Dealing with a multi-GB ERP test database with millions of rows in hundreds of tables is not the same thing as using Django tools to quickly setup a few dozen fake tables and data derived from its ORM-backed schema.  That's true for both the costs of managing system refreshes between tests as well as the likelihood that using Mocks will hide problems under much later.

Do you/your project practice a lot of Mocking?  Unit testing vs Integration testing?


Some well regarded developers are on the record as dismissing Mocks for hiding and/or inducing complexity.  While others tend to privilege integration testing, i.e. exercising a number of components to produce an externally observable unit of work over unit testing - exercising a sub-component's internal logic.
Both forms of tests could be using the same testing frameworks - say the JUnit family - and just differ in emphasis.  Still unit testing leans more towards mocking, while integration testing leans more towards interaction with actual databases.

Even projects that are more focused on integration testing can also find value in granular unit testing:  if you have a particularly hairy function you may want to exercise with numerous calls with different arguments and edge cases.  Those don't really benefit all that much from repeatedly calling a database to really update it.  A Mock would be preferable in that case.

That would doubly apply if you planned to stress it some more with automated calls from a fuzzer.



Forget the article, do not mock a database. Fake a database instead.
Database needs a flow. When you save something, you need to be able to read it afterwards. Mocks do not allow that, unless you specify it yourself, which is why mocks are not suitable for a database. Fake a database using a simple structure, that allows you to read your data after you save it, and is able to perform logic of your queries by code (like filtering, pagination etc.).
(maybe off-topic, but someone may read this question/answers and remember 'always mock a database in unit tests', which is wrong)
